# Ctrl+Enter и Enter js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как выполнить функцию при нажатии <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> не выполняя функцию по нажатию <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

```js
$("#text").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("enter");
  } else if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log("ctrl+enter");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: поменять местами условия???

Comment: keydown срабатывает при нажатии на клавишу сразу. Как только вы нажмёте, напимер, Ctrl, он вроде и не станет ждать нажатия ещё и на Enter. Лучше бы сменить событие на keyup. Ну и условие более узкое лучше в самом деле поставить выше.

Comment: @DmitriiSedov ставьте ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно поменять местами условие!

```js
$("#text").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("ctrl+enter");
  } else if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    console.log("enter");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```